# How do you convay Variables, Boolean constants, integer constants, and float constants as allowed operands in a BNF grammar

Tags: grammar, bnf

I am writing a description of the Boolean expressions of C++. This is what I have so far

```
<expr> -> <expr> && <term>
    | <term>
<term> -> <factor> || <term>
    | <factor>
<factor> -> (<expr>)
      | <id>
      | !<factor>
```

I need to show that Variables, Boolean constants, integer constants, and float constants are allowed as operands in my BNF. My question is, how do I do that?

My first thought is to just do something like  INT_LIT | VAR_LIT | FLO_LIT| BOOL_LIT, but my understanding is severely lacking in this topic.

Also, my understanding is that, in plain English, this BNF says:

An expression and a term can be an expression or a expression and a term

A factor OR a term or a factor OR a factor can be a term

Am I totally off?

Comment: It's hard to know how seriously you're interested in this, but FWIW there's an "informative" grammar in Appendix A of the Standard - you can find a draft [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf).  You could also find quite a lot of BNF and boost spirit grammars for expression parsing with a 'net search or three.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?